# Meteor - Cannot access custom user field upon registration

Tags: meteor, reactjs

Upon a user registration, I've added a new field for a Meteor user using React as my front end:

**React component:**

```
Accounts.createUser({
 email: trimInput(this.state.email),
 password: this.state.password,
 username: trimInput(this.state.username),
 regId: 1, // I need to access this to show/hide fields elsewhere.
});
```

**Server:**

```
// I assume this is how it's done?
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  user['regId'] = options.regId
  return user
});
```

In `meteor mongo` I can see the newly added field: `"regId": "1"`. Great. Now in browswer console: `Meteor.user.find().fetch()` does not include the field. `Meteor.user().regId` returns `undefined`. Huh?

What is the correct way to approach something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think previous answer is good, but you should improve in order to remove
`Meteor.subscribe("userData");` 
in every controller by publish automatically.

```
`Meteor.publish(null, function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                             {fields: {'regId': 1}});
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});`
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer because I was having issues with new registration. Their new field was not showing but your answer solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users), I needed to pub/sub the data:

**Server:**

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                             {fields: {'regId': 1}});
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});
```

**Client:**

```
Meteor.subscribe("userData");
```

Now you'll have access to `Meteor.user().regId`